# The code doesn't execute my main function when using DJI OSDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I have an N3 with OSDK running on a RPi. I am able to run the telemetry-sample without any problem. However, when I try to make my own program, the program doesn't execute my main function.

I build the program just like the provided samples, using CMAKE. However, the sample runs fine, but mine stops right before entering the main function. Does anyone have an idea as to why this may be happening? Am i missing something?

Here is the output of my program:

```
argv[1] = UserConfig.txt
Read App ID
User Configuration read successfully. 


STATUS/1 @ init, L56: Attempting to open device /dev/ttyAMA0 with baudrate 230400...

STATUS/1 @ init, L66: ...Serial started successfully.

STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L762: Device Serial No. = [redacted]

STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L764: Hardware = N3

STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L765: Firmware = 3.2.36.8

ERRORLOG/1 @ initVirtualRC, L1188: Virtual RC is not supported on this platform!

STATUS/1 @ activate, L1398: version 0x3022408

STATUS/1 @ activate, L1411: Activation successful

STATUS/1 @ verify, L247: Verify subscription successful.
STATUS/1 @ initGimbal, L926: Checking if gimbal is connected ...
STATUS/1 @ startPackage, L353: Start package 0 result: 0.
STATUS/1 @ startPackage, L355: Package 0 info: freq=50, nTopics=1.

STATUS/1 @ removePackage, L471: Remove package 0 successful.
STATUS/1 @ initGimbal, L970: Gimbal not mounted!

STATUS/1 @ reset, L570: Reset Subscription Successful.
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction, I had copied my CMAKE file from another directory into my new project directory. This caused the CMakeCache to be linked to the old directory and was executing old code.

I updated the CMakeCache to include the new project's directory and everything worked fine.

Leaving this up, in case someone does this mistake too.